# Firebug doesn't work with multi-process Firefox

Tags: firefox, firebug

I miss Firebug. Everytime I try to run it I get this error:

> Firebug doesn't support multiprocess Firefox (e10s). So you either need to disable e10s or upgrade to Firebug 3 alpha.

A button that reads `Upgrade and Restart` follows. It doesn't work.

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the installation of Firebug 3 fails for you, you may need to [go to `about:config`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config) and set `xpinstall.signatures.required` to `false`.
If the installation then still fails, you can download it manually from this page:

https://getfirebug.com/releases/firebug/3.0/

On a last resort you can also disable e10s by unchecking Firefox menu > *Options* > *Enable multi-process Firefox/Firefox Developer Edition/Nightly*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How do I go to `about:config` ?

Comment: Just type it into the address bar and hit Enter. I linked it now to an article, explaining `about:config` in detail.

Comment: Thanks man turning `xpinstall.signature.required` to `false` worked!.